# Cordova build failed for Windows

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, windows-phone-7, ionic3

I want to test my app on Windows / Windows Mobile. For this I first installed `Visual Studio Community 2017` and then I  downloaded `Windows 10 SDK & Mobile Development with JavaScript`. After that I added Windows platform, and 2 lines of code in `config.xml` that looks like below

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
<engine name="windows" spec="5.0.0" />
```

Now when I run `ionic cordova build windows -- --arch="x64"` I am facing below error

```
Configuration : debug
Platform      : x64
Patching 10 in prebuild event...
Injected base.js reference to the /www/index.html
Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from /www/index.html
Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from /www/index.html
Error: AppPackages doesn't exists
```

What is missing?